# Negation of 8-bit hexadecimal

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am looking for a mathematical formula / algorithm to find the negation of a 8-bit hexadecimal without having to expand into a binary form.

E.g;

0000BDDA -> 48602

FFFF4226 -> -48602

Need to get from 0000BDDA -> FFFF4226 without 2' complements / expanding it to binary.

I've been cracking my head at it but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Bits are inherently binary, two's complement is inherently binary. 8 bits is two hex digits but your examples have 8. You say you don't want two's complement and you don't want to expand to binary so, in that case, the negation of $\mathrm{0000BDDA}$ is simply $\mathrm{-0000BDDA}$.

Comment: Look at what you are doing, it is just 16's complement...

Comment: @David Richerby Sorry for the confusion, what I meant is that I am looking for another method to find the negative value of 48602 other than using the two complement's method which is to flip the bits and add 1.

Comment: @misheekoh The negative value of $48602$ is $-48602$.  Correspondingly, the negative value of $\mathrm{0000BDDA}$ is just $-\mathrm{0000BDDA}$, with a good, old-fashioned minus sign (in the same way, $-5$ in binary is just $-101$). Now, the fact that you're saying that $-48602$ is $\mathrm{FFFF4226}$ and not some negative value indicates that you're using some encoding of negative numbers as positive numbers. The smart money says you're using two's complement. And you're asking how to do two's complement without doing two's complement. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same formula as you do for two's complement. First, compute the *complement* of the number by complementing all letters. Then add 1. Complementing works using the following table:
$$
0 \leftrightarrow F, 1 \leftrightarrow E, 2 \leftrightarrow D, 3 \leftrightarrow C, 4 \leftrightarrow B, 5 \leftrightarrow A, 6 \leftrightarrow 9, 7 \leftrightarrow 8.
$$
Example: starting with 0000BDDA, we first get FFFF4225, and after adding 1, we get FFFF4226.

Why does this work? Exercise.

Comment: But let's say if I have FFFFFFFF, I convert it to 00000000 and after adding 1, I get 00000001? Which is not the negation of FFFFFFFF?

Comment: FFFFFFFF represents -1, so this example does work out.